# Why can't I activate the Goddess Cube?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

I have reached Eldin Volcano and am trying to activate the Goddess Cube at the end of the forked path.  No matter how many times I hit it, it won't flash.  I have followed the guide, so don't think I have missed anything.  I didn't do the Pumpkin Juice side quest.  Could that be why it isn't working?

Comment: Just to state the obvious: you do charge your sword and light comes out of the sword and hits the cube, right?

Comment: Yes.  I was able to activate the 1st one, but not the 2nd.

Comment: Check a guide in order to determine what the reward is for doing the Pumpkin Juice quest.  What does the guide say about this cube exactly?  I had no problem activating both Cubes at the apporpriate time.

Comment: Some of the cubes don't light up until you've progressed further into the game. Try checking back after you've completed the Lanayru Mining Facility dungeon.

Comment: I moved on in the game and went to the next goddess cube.  It is inside the volcano where you have to free fall.  It also would not activate.  I'm thinking I need to start the whole game over because I have obviously missed something.  Ugh!!

Comment: How close to the Goddess Cube are you standing?  You need to be right next to it.  Also, can you take a screenshot or find one online so we can see which cube you're having trouble with?

Answer (score 1):

Hold your Wiimote (sword) up and let it charge a Skyward Strike, then slash it so the sword beam hits the Goddess Cube.  This ALWAYS works on Goddess Cubes, there's no reason why it shouldn't.  The corresponding chests may not be obtainable right away (in the sky), but there's no bugs about these things so it should work perfectly fine if you hit it with a proper Skyward Strike.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the Goddess Cube across the lava river (in the room one or two before the dragon), then you can't reach it until you get the True Master Sword.  Until you get the True Master Sword, your Skyward Strike is not powerful enough to make it across the lava river.

If you are playing in Hero Mode, you can get the Goddess Cube right away because your Skyward Strike is already at full power.